# Spartacus custom checkout configuration issue

Tags: checkout, spartacus-storefront

I'm trying to make a custom checkout with 2 steps (form and summary)  but when I go to checkout my component replaces all the page.
I guess I have something wrong on my config:
checkoutConfigModule.module.ts:

```
imports: [
    ConfigModule.withConfig({
      routing: {
        routes: {  checkoutShippingMode: { paths: ['checkout/shipping-mode'] },  },
      },
      checkout: {
        steps: [ {
              id: 'shippingMode',
              name: 'checkoutProgress.shippingMode',
              routeName: 'checkoutShippingMode',
              type: [CheckoutStepType.SHIPPING_ADDRESS, CheckoutStepType.DELIVERY_MODE ],
              }...
```

my component.module:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    CheckoutOrderComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(staticRoutes),
    ConfigModule.withConfig({
      cmsComponents: {
        CheckoutShippingMode: {
          component: CheckoutOrderComponent,
          // guards: [AuthGuard, CartNotEmptyGuard, CheckoutGuard],
        }
      }
    }),
  ],
```

What I'm missing? Maybe the guards have are the issue??
Thanks for the help (editado)

Comment: Let me just ask few questions to fill the gaps:
- What CMS components did you configured in backoffice for both of your checkout pages?
- Are you redirected to different page when you open `checkout/shipping-mode`?

Comment: I made a back component named CheckoutShippingMode and in the front I have CheckoutOrderComponent.
checkout/shipping-mode redirects to the same page but doesnt load header or footer.
I had to remove the guards
Thanks Marcin